# Can't launch applications after a while under gnome fallback

Tags: gnome, 13.10

I use gnome-fallback under ubuntu 13.10 (but it was also the case in 13.04). After some time, without any action, I can't launch any new applications. The old ones continue to work normally, but I just can't launch anything. 
Any ideas?

best,

Comment: They wallpaper become grey too when this happen...

Comment: When trying to launch an application in the terminal, I got something like "Could not open X display. Maximum number of clients reached".